# Generated form asp-action tag helper includes id

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

I have the following form

```
<form asp-action="Edit">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ReleaseDate" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="ReleaseDate" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="ReleaseDate" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Genre" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Genre" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Genre" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Price" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Price" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

After running the project and going to *Edit* action view, i see in the source code in browser that `<form asp-action="Edit">`is translated into `<form action="/Movies/Edit/2" method="post">`

My question is, how does ASP know about the `id` (2) in `"/Movies/Edit/2"`.

Comment: you are sending the id over the URL. On the other side you have specified the action Edit that it is accepting an ID. So it will render the ID from URL. And next time copy the Controller and the URL you are calling.

Comment: @SehaxX what do you mean "render the ID from URL"?

Answer (score 0):

In this markup the ASP defines what is its ID to be passed in POST when its form is sent to the controller.

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
```

A hidden field allows your entity Id to be kept in the form without being seen or modified by users when a form is submitted.

See this documentation below as a supplement to your question.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The edit form should always be delivered from an URL that has an ID in the URL according to our routing rules, something like /Movies/edit/1.

The form is always going to post back to that same URL, /Movies/edit/1.

The MVC framework will be able to pull that ID out of the URL and pass it as a parameter.

Refer to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_core/asp.net_core_razor_edit_form.htm

Comment: If i change `<form asp-action="Edit">` to `<form asp-action="Details"`> it doesn't go to the same URL.

Comment: @chakmeshma That's ture.It seems to only works for `Edit`